# Microsoft Outlook Office 365 desktop app is not showing desktop notifications

Tags: email, notifications, microsoft-outlook-365

For some reason, my Microsoft Outlook 365 desktop application is not showing desktop notifications for new mail. Does Outlook 365 need to be open in order to show the notifications? I would guess *not* but if so that's the issue.

Otherwise, what else could be the issue? *Below*, I've listed what I've tried so far. I installed this earlier today so I haven't messed with any other settings.

1) *All Settings > System
From the panel on the left select: Notifications & Actions.
In the "Get notifications from these senders" section at the bottom, click on Outlook.
Make sure that you have enabled all notification options.
Close Settings*

2) *File > Options > Mail.
Under Message arrival, select Display a Desktop Alert check box and then select OK.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for new Mail to show, Outlook needs to be open. You can minimize it, but Outlook needs to receive the mail for the icon to light up.

Comment: Ah! Well, that solves my issue *and* answers my question. It was simply a misunderstanding on my end. Thank you!

Comment: Good luck  - Glad it is all working for you